# Is it advisable to let my cat mate two months after having given birth?

Tags: cats, health, breeding

My cat (Persian) is in heat two months after having given birth! Yes, she has stopped breastfeeding the kittens as they have been adopted. However, in case she mates with my male cat and gets pregnant again, will it pose health complications in the future or should I let nature takes it's course?
(I've kept them in separate rooms for the moment).
I'm in dire need of answers. Please suggest.

Comment: Do you plan on having more kittens?

Comment: I never really mated cats, but your kittens must have been weaned off at most a week ago, so your cat only had a week of rest. I am sure someone qualified will answer soon, but my gut tells me it is not a good idea.

Comment: I would suggest getting your cat spayed. They shouldn't be used as breeding machines to make money from

Comment: Are you up to having more kittens in the house so soon?  Are you giving the kittens away or is this a business ?

Answer (score 4):

**Unless you want to have more kittens I would suggest spaying your cat.**

It is not about letting nature take its course, being pregnant and giving birth and even being in heat itself is very stressful for your cat.

Also consider that many animals each year are euthanized in shelters because they are unable to find a home or are brought in by former owners. This also happens to pure-bred animals!

[11 Facts About Animal Homelessness - US](https://www.dosomething.org/us/facts/11-facts-about-animal-homelessness)

That being said you should give your cat time between pregnancies to get back some energy. Giving birth and feeding kittens takes quite some energy away from your cat so give her time to rest in between. Just like with us humans birthing is draining and stressful for cats.

[Stressed by maternity cats - Paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-2615/10/5/903)